# how to use Styled-components in reactjs for the componenet name contain special Character?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I try to use reactstrap in my app.

If I use the CSS Stylesheet sytle it works:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
...
<p className="text-warning">
  Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
</p>
```

But as other module introduce,

I want use boostrap in CSS module style.

```
import bs from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
...
<p className={bs.text-warning}>
  Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
</p>
```

It doesn't working as fellow error：

```
ReferenceError: warning is not defined
```

You can see it only recognize warning not text-warning. how to make the jsx engine recoginize the whole style name rather then just then the last part of it.

Comment: `bs['text-warning]`

Comment: I test bs['text-warning'], it seems not working, I use react 16.2.0 and reactstrap 4.8.0 @HunterMcMillen

Comment: Can you post the updated code that you tried? Also, I could have been due to my typo in my comment :\. The full statement should be `bs['text-warning']`, with a leading _and_ trailing single quote